# pick up image from div & add as background images

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have the following html being created by a CMS.

```
<div class="item-image" style="margin-left: -154px; margin-right: -154px;"> 
   <img src="/images/header_images/placeholder_image.jpg" alt="" itemprop="image" />
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to grab the image from the img tag and add it to the style of the "item-image" div as a background-image?

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/96h4wmkf/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var imageSrc = $(".item-image img").attr("src");
$(".item-image").css("background-image", "url('" + imageSrc + "')");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.item-image').css('background-image', 'url('+$('.item-image img').attr('src')+')');`

Answer (score 1):

This will get every .item-image div and apply the respective background removing the original image

```
$('.item-image').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var url = that.find('img').attr('src');
  that.empty().css({'background':'url("' + url + '") no-repeat 50% 50%'});    
});
```

Comment: Why the 50% 50%? The rest seems ok.

Comment: This centers the image inside the div, fell free to remove them or change them as you wish

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set background image for 'item-image' element
Try this:

```
var src = $('.item-image img').attr('src');
$()$('.item-image').css('background-image', 'url('+ src +');');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Image `src` into parent div backgound

   `$('.item-image').css('background-image', 
                          'url('+$('.item-image img').attr('src')+')');`
2. but still background won't show up because div need `height` and `width` so you need to get also image `w/h`

   `$('.item-image').css({'height' : $('.item-image img').outerHeight(), 
                        'width' : $('.item-image img').outerWidth()});`
3. Now `<img/>` tag not useful if you have used background same image, so remove image

   `$('.item-image img').remove();`

**combine code**

```
$('.item-image').css({
     'background-image': 'url('+$('.item-image img').attr('src')+')', 
     'height' : $('.item-image img').outerHeight(), 
     'width' : $('.item-image img').outerWidth()});
$('.item-image img').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your jsfiddle with an example. I've made the assumption that you want to set the width and height of the div with the values from the original image. If not, you should be able to update it to your own needs. Remember you need to set width and height or you won't see anything at all!

I've used commenting in the javascript for some explanation.

HTML:

```
<div class="item-image" style="margin-left: -154px; margin-right: -154px;"> 
    <img src="http://mylonhom.t8.ext.starberry.com/images/header_images/placeholder_image.jpg" alt="" itemprop="image" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// We wan't to grab all div's with the item-image class.
// Since it is a class, we must prepare to have more than one div
// with the item-image class
$('.item-image').each(function (itemIndex, item) {
    var $item, $image, imageSrc, imageWidth, imageHeight;

    // Set a reference to the div and fetch the first available image
    $item = $(item);
    $image = $item.find('img').eq(0);

    // Did we fetch an image?
    if ($image) {
        // Let's fetch its source attribute
        imageSrc = $image.attr('src');
        imageWidth = $image.outerWidth();
        imageHeight = $image.outerHeight();

        // Now set it as a background to the div
        $item.css({
            'background-image': 'url(\''+imageSrc+'\')',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'width' : imageWidth + 'px',
            'height': imageHeight + 'px'
        });

        // Finally, remove the img tag from the div, we don't
        // need it there anymore
        $image.remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96h4wmkf/4/